# Why do I get "_fg_" instead of "fg_"?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
  if (evt.keyCode >= 65 && evt.keyCode <= 90) {
    let command = document.getElementById("cmdInput").textContent;
    let str2 = command.substring(0, command.length - 1) + evt.key + "_";
    console.log(str2);
    document.getElementById("cmdInput").textContent = str2;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="cmdInput">_</div>
```

As you can see, I get "_fg_" instead of "fg_". Why? Why isn't the leading underscore not moving as of my typing?

[image: What I get while typing "fg".]

Comment: Your code works. Look at the snippet I added.

Comment: Where did you add the snippet? I only see my own post.

Comment: There's a big blue button under your code named "Run code snippet".

Comment: Yes, but it's referring to my own code, isn't it? Where is yours?

Comment: Yes, and your code works.

Comment: How are you explaining my screenshot then? There's something going wrong with the original underscore.

Comment: I can't with the code you've provided because your code works.

Comment: So it may be a problem with the browser.